# Starting a 2D Game in Qt

Tags: qt, opengl, 2d

i'm trying to start a 2D game in Qt.  I'm trying to find any tutorials on how to start developing it...

Any good tutorial there on internet? (If it's possible Qt 4.7+)

Comment: There are tons of OpenGL, QT, QT OpenGL, OpenGL 2D, and video game tutorials on the net.  QT will have very little to do with your final game, so I'd suggest you start looking into the other pieces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenGl by itself in Qt is not different from Opengl without Qt. The only difference is the way you create your OpenGl window.

You need to derive the QGLWidget class and overload the PaintGL-memberfunction. Take a look at the HelloGL example (which is already quite extensive).

Now that you have your OpenGl window look for normal OpenGl tutorials which are available all over the internet.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Qt for 2D games, I'd let Qt handle the OpenGL aspect of it and just use QGraphicsScene et al.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider using a Qt/QML based engine, giving you the advantages of cross-platform support and many useful game components for handling multiple display resolutions & aspect ratios, animations, particles, physics, multi-touch, gestures, path finding and more ([API reference](http://v-play.net/doc/vplay-group.html)), take a look at [V-Play](http://v-play.net/) (v-play.net).

They also provide you with several tutorials for different skill levels and come with ready-to-use game templates for the most successful game genres like tower defense, platform games or puzzle games. ([V-Play examples & demos](http://v-play.net/doc/daily/))